# Импорт array.java файла в виде массива

Tags: java

Приветствую! Уважаемые знатоки, пожалуйста можете натолкнуть на путь истинный.
Собственно задача:

Мне нужно, чтобы сохранялся файл в виде " файл-массив ".
К примеру у php - это делается очень просто.

**file.php**:

```
<?php return array(1,2,3);
```

Есть ли такая возможность в java?

Посмотрел, что возможность сохранения объектов имеется.

```
try (ObjectOutputStream ObjectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FILE))) { 
    ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(OBJECT); 
}
```

После сохранения объекта, чтобы загрузить делаю так:

```
final FileInputStream FileOutputStream = new FileInputStream(FILE); 
final ObjectInputStream ObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(FileOutputStream); 
OBJECT = (ConcurrentHashMap) ObjectInputStream.readObject();
```

Есть ли способ, чтобы экспортировать/ипортировать массивы? В виде файла-массива, а не объекта.

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в php, но чем принципиально массив лучше объекта? И почему вы хотите сохранить именно в него?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov массив не лучше и не хуже объекта. Это просто такой тоже себе объект, задуманный для хранения упорядоченного набора других объектов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Массивы в java так же являются объектами. Кроме того, что массив тоже объект, так он ещё такой объект, который является Serializable. И как любой Serializable объект может быть как записан в файл:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
try (ObjectOutputStream ObjectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(FILE))) { 
    ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(arr); 
}
```

так и прочитан из файла:

```
final FileInputStream FileOutputStream = new FileInputStream(FILE); 
final ObjectInputStream ObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(FileOutputStream); 
int[] arr = (int[]) ObjectInputStream.readObject();
```

Ну и ещё элементы массива должны быть Serializable

Comment: лучше сразу json/yaml/etc

Comment: Ах вот в чем дело. Даже и не сообразил, что речь о всяких include, которые вставляется исходный код со всем, что угодно прямо во время работы. Так вот в java так конечно не получится. Это же компилируемый язык программирования, а не язык описания счётчиков посетителей.

Comment: @Etki, не лучше. Это решение не подходит. К тому - же, Sergey - сказал правильно, правда этот вариант я уже рассматривал, и не подумал, что как же так, тут нельзя, просто взять и сделать return {}; в самом файле, так как строгий язык и чистый ООП, нужно работать напрямую из файлика и сохранять только plain файлики или конкретный class - enum для импорта, опять-же в класс или в главный Класс main метода. просто отрывок скрипт-кода, не воспроизводит и даже не компилируется.

Comment: @And как связаны return и json и почему не подходит, если меняется только формат сериализации?

Comment: @Etki, не подходит для моей архитектуры, так-как массивы нативные, мне проще на этом завязываться, работает гораздо шустрее при больших объемах.

Comment: Можно применить в java скрипты на скриптовых языках. javascript например сразу из коробки. В скрипте определяешь массив на javascript, и через всякие биндинги получаешь его в java. Но это всё не в одну строку конечно же. И вряд ли для дела загрузки массива лучше загрузки из файла.

Comment: @And да вы серьезно что ли

Comment: @etki, да не, я забыл, что давн-кастинг возможен и с массивами разными уровнями вложенности `Arrays.deepToString((String[][][]) OBJECT)`.

Comment: @And даункастинг здесь тоже никакой роли не играет, вы просто методично занимаетесь самобичеванием. Скорость сериализации/десериализации у вас совершенно точно не будет оказывать критического воздействия на быстродействие.

Comment: @etki, это нужно было для сохранения массивов и вновь его чтения, отправки, что вам не понятно? Сериализация и так используется.